# What is this tree?

Tags: identification, trees

What is this tree? Located in Northeast Ohio...
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add any more information like, is it deciduous? does if flower?

Comment: Yes, it is deciduous. I don't remember if it flowers. These are photos from last year and right now it is too early for new leaves/flowers.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's probably Acer negundo, common name Box Elder - that variety of maple has variably shaped leaf arrangements, as well as variation in individual leaves. I can't see how the leaves are arranged in the picture, but the shape of some of them would indicate one of the Acers (not all have the classic fan shaped, five pointed leaf), and the fact the keys or samaras are held in pairs on long stems in clusters rather than in a single, long raceme fits with Acer negundo. Image of leaves, showing a typical arrangement, plus images of flowers, shoots and bark (which we can't see detail of in your picture) below for you to compare

https://www.minnesotawildflowers.info/tree/boxelder

Comment: Thanks. Once the leaves grow back I'll take a look at how they're arranged and look for buds/flowers.

Comment: @Bamboo Your answer makes more sense to me. As I am more familiar with tree anmes in english, it seems that this one is also called ash-leaved maple

Comment: @LaurentDuval - not in the UK its not! Common name here is actually Box Elder... ash leaved maple sounds more like something the States would use as a name - and its not even 'ash leaved' either, ash leaves are composite with 7,9 or more leaflets to a leaf, so that name doesn't make any sense to me at all, apart from the 'maple' bit, you sure its given that name elsewhere? that said, I'm not 100% on this ID, need to see a single branch with leaves on and get a close look at the bark...

Comment: @Bamboo "ash-leaved maple, and maple ash are its most common names in the United States; in Britain and Ireland it is also known as ashleaf maple." from the wiki page. Not my knowledge ;)

Comment: @LaurentDuval7 Aye, that's what Wiki says - but then Wiki says all sorts of things...! If I can find another, horticultural source which says the term ash maple is used in the UK, I'll let you know...

Comment: @LaurentDuval - yep, found a reference to Ashleaf Maple on the Hainault Forestry Commission site in the UK - its a less common and little used name, secondary to Box Elder. I find it confusing its called Box Elder, never made sense to me, never mind Ashleaf Maple...and why I loathe common names, you never know what anyone's talking about because it depends where they come from which common name they use.

Answer (score 1):

A first guess, based on the samaras (known as "keys" or "helicopter seeds") and the lance-shaped leaves, (very) slightly toothed on edges: an [ash tree](http://treedoctor.anr.msu.edu/ash/ashtree_id.html)?